# Need to Run Google Sheets function Twice to Work Properly

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run pretty simple code to sort data across multiple sheets in Google Sheets. The problem that I am having is that I need to run it twice for everything to sort properly. Here are the functions that are going into the overall `doForAllTabs` function:

```
    function Order() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort([{column: 4, ascending: true}, {column: 7, ascending: true}]);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};

function MasterOrder() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B:I').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort([{column: 9, ascending: true}, {column: 4, ascending: true}, {column: 7, ascending: true}]);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};




function TeacherSort() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:C').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};


function doForAllTabs () {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    if(sheet.getSheetName() == "Master"){
      sheet.activate();
      MasterOrder();
    }
    else if(sheet.getSheetName() == "Year 1"){
      sheet.activate();
      Order();
    }
    else if(sheet.getSheetName() == "Year 2"){
      sheet.activate();
      Order();
    }
    else if(sheet.getSheetName() == "Year 3"){
      sheet.activate();
      Order();
    }
    else if(sheet.getSheetName() != "Calculations"){
      sheet.activate();
      TeacherSort();
    }
  })
}
```

From the look of it, when I run `doForAllTabs` just once it will run `MasterOrder`, but not any of the other functions in the other sheets.
Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function doForAllTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  const years = ["Year 1","Year 2","Year 3"];
  allSheets.forEach(function (sh) {
    let name = sh.getName();
    let idx = years.indexOf(sh.getName());
    if (name == "Master") {
      sh.getRange('B1:I' + sh.getLastRow()).offset(1, 0).sort([{ column: 9, ascending: true }, { column: 4, ascending: true }, { column: 7, ascending: true }]);
    }
    else if (~idx) {
      sh.getRange('A1:G' + sh.getLastRow()).sort([{ column: 4, ascending: true }, { column: 7, ascending: true }]);
    }
    else if (name != "Calculations") {
      sh.getRange('A1:C' + sh.getLastRow()).sort({ column: 3, ascending: true });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That worked great. Thank you for your help. Would you mind explaining what is being done so I can learn from this? How does the addition of sh.getLastRow() change the function?

Comment: I just combined everything into one function and kept the ranges from generating nulls at the end by using sh.getLastRow() and reduced the number of unnecessary function calls.